# Are the two prime ideals containing same idempotents always the same?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, idempotents

> If two prime ideals contain the same non trivial idempotents, what can we say about those ideals? Are they equal?

Comment: Is there any reason you think this is true? Some context would help people answer, and probably help give answers that are better for your purpose

Answer (score 4):

Consider the ring $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ (which is arguably the simplest ring having non-trivial idempotents, so it should be one of the first examples we look at). Its non-trivial idempotents are $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$, and its prime ideals are those ideals of the form $\mathbb{Z}\times P$ and $P\times\mathbb{Z}$ where $P\subset\mathbb{Z}$ is a prime ideal. Thus $\mathbb{Z}\times (2)$ and $\mathbb{Z}\times (3)$ are both prime ideals containing the same non-trivial idempotents (namely, only $(1,0)$) while not being identical.

Comment: Since the OP didn't actually require the ring to have any nontrivial idempotents, even $\mathbb Z$ would give a counterexample,